# Matlab: datevec and CSV file

Tags: matlab, datetime, csv, file-io, vector

I'm reading a CSV file that looks like the following:

```
  date        time      price volume exchange
20070813    10:26:38    7.626   3       E
20070925    12:58:24    7.535   69      E
20071218    10:45:47    8.24    50      E
20080117    14:23:58    8.046   100     E
20080117    16:22:44    8.04    1       E
20080319    13:52:40    8.25    1       E 
20080709    12:18:29    9.9     3       E
```

I read the data like this:

```
fid = fopen('E:\Tick Data\Data Output\NGQ11.csv','r'); 
[c] = fscanf(fid, '%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%c');
```

I want a column vector to hold all the volume data, which I create like this:

```
vv = c(6:7:end); %VOLUME VECTOR
```

And now I want a vector `tt` to hold all the date and time data, so that I can say

```
[yyyy,mm,dd,hr,mn] = datevec(tt);
```

My question is, how do I declare this vector `tt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
fid = fopen('data.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f %s', 'HeaderLines',1, 'CollectOutput',true);
fclose(fid);

[dt,val,exch] = deal(C{:});
dt = datenum(strcat(dt(:,1),{' '},dt(:,2)), 'yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS');
```

Now `dt` contains the *serial date number* representation of the date/time values for each record (fraction of days since "January 0, 0000"). You can then use functions like `datevec` and `datestr` to manipulate and format it:

```
[Y, M, D, H, MN, S] = datevec(dt)
```

`val` is a N-by-2 matrix where the first column is "price", second column is "volume". Similarly `exch` is a cell array of strings with the exchange symbols.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to understand the syntax of textscan; if there were no headers would that appear as `C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f %s', 'CollectOutput',true);`?

Comment: Yes that appears to work. When I run this line `[dt,val,exch] = deal(C{:})` I get lines that look like `'20110523,09:24:26,4.418,1,E'      ''` followed by a large number of `NaN   NaN` followed by a large number of `''`. But the next line says datenum failed, Failed on converting date string to date number. Why is this?

Comment: @siegel: The data you posted was delimited by spaces/tabs. If your actual data uses commas, you should specify it as such.. Try the `'Delimiter'` option of textscan. It would help if you post a sample of the actual CSV file

Comment: I think I figured it out! Missing a comma in `'yyyymmdd, HH:MM:SS'`

Comment: is it working now? (I assume you added `textscan(..., 'Delimiter',',')`)

Comment: Yes, it's working, although a little slow. For a 5 megabyte csv it's taking 21 seconds.

Comment: @siegel: TEXTSCAN is usually fast, so I doubt its an IO issue. I think the conversion to serial date numbers is the slow part. Insert a couple of tic/toc in between.. How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: I used the profiler, and the datenum function takes 91% of the time, with strcat taking up 6% of the time. 170299 lines in the csv file.

Comment: well there you have it, datetime string parsing is the slow part as I suspected. Depending on what you intend to do with the date/time columns, perhaps you can get away with just treating it as a char-matrix and extract year/month/etc.. by simple matrix indexing. What I'm trying to say is unless you actually need to, avoiding the parsing step which I guess is expensive for 170K strings

Comment: well its not that slow. For example the following code takes less than 3 seconds to finish on my machine, nowhere near 21 sec: `tic, dt = datenum(repmat({'20131231 23:59:59'},[170000,1]), 'yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS'); toc`